# TestNG, Junit and log4j

Tags: junit, log4j, testng

Is there any easy way to configure log4j so that in unit tests I only print the stacktrace of the failing tests without having noise in the output on the shell?
Right now when I execute tests I can see the output printed by the classes I am testing. I want to avoid that since it's not bringing any value for passing tests

Comment: Have you considered raising log levels in your log4j configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to have `log4j.properties` file under `src/test/resources` with content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

As result all your production classes will not log but the jUnit or testNG will print the failed tests as you expect.

Comment: that's interesting. I have a question. the path you suggested /src/test/resources is because of your dir structure?
Because my tests are not in the src/ folder, but in /test/com/blabla

Comment: The suggested path is a general standard of maven project. If you have other project structure in this case you need directly specify it. Say, for Eclipse project you may configure manually in project preferencies.

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test, set the log level to the level at which stacktraces are being logged:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```